# Are there any good resources for the Actor Model in Common Lisp, and good documents on the Actor Model in general?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, lisp, common-lisp, actor

Are there any good implementations, documents, etc. of Actor-esque concurrency libraries in Common Lisp? CLiki is rather vague on this subject.

And no, I'm not using Clojure and I won't use it for this.

Comment: So is not a "research site" (google is) .. perhaps the question can be specified better?

Comment: I had managed to find CL-ACTORS, but it was rather poorly documented (at least, for my level of multi-threaded experience), and any search for Actor Model things by themselves would invariantly bring up Scala libraries. I was wondering if anyone else had a similar problem and could point me to good resources on the subject or, better yet, implementations of it in CL.

Comment: There was an interesting project http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-muproc/, but I doubt it's under active development now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zeromq (www.zeromq.org) has bindings for Common Lisp. It doesn't quite support the actor model (named pipes rather than named actors) but it might be what you are looking for.

Cliki suggests cl-actors (http://www.cliki.net/cl-actors) but I have no experience with this.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use cl-actors while it's so incomplete...